# File tests in Python?

Tags: python

I'd like to use Python 3.3.3 to test for the existence of a backup file.

Something like this:

```
if backup does not exist:
    create it
    write to backup

otherwise:
    run other procedures not related to backup file
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: please search before asking, this has been asked and answered.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-using-python?lq=1

Answer (score 5):

Use [`os.path.exists`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) or [`os.path.isfile`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isfile('/path/to/file')
False
```

Comment: Please insert here the usual warning of introducing race conditions etc...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [os.path.exists](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.exists#os.path.exists).